# Shopware 6 - bug with Email template variables

Tags: shopware, shopware6

Did someone has a problem with email templates?
In my case when I use email template in Flow builder for trigger "checkout.order.payment_method.changed" email template with type "order confirmation" doesn't work properly. Problem with variables: currency and addresses are null but other variables works properly.
Interesting when I use the same template in Flow builder for trigger "checkout.order.placed"  all vars working properly.
p.s. I've updated all extensions and my Shopware version is v6.4.9.0 Stable Version
Maybe it's a Shopware bug or conflict between plugins?

Answer (score 1):

There are some inconsistencies regarding the data available between different Flow-Builder Events. I noticed something similar and created an issue for it [here](https://github.com/shopware/platform/issues/2494).
Maybe you can add your case there as this sounds related.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the exact content of your order confirmation template, eg if it is the default content or if you made changes, it is hard to tell why this wouldn't work. I tested this on the latest release as of today `6.4.13.0` and the combination of said trigger and template seems to work fine. Looking at the history of the [`OrderStateChangeEventListener`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/80f7f2afdba3771c9f500e2df2096d26ee3beb67/src/Core/Checkout/Order/Listener/OrderStateChangeEventListener.php#L230), the criteria for the order should've included `currency` and `addresses` associations for a while already, including your version. As @newgennerd already said there could potentially be differences between the criteria used for fetching order for state change events and those used for order placed events, as the latter would be the common use case for the order confirmation. So you should keep that in mind.